# Onload javascript with php doesn't trigger the onload functions

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this code that is supposed to trigger an ajax call for every count of likes from a php like system I made. I guess it doesn't call because of the html tags but I need something like that.

In the following code I know the user ,id and since I am calling it from a fetch_array from php and mysql

`<span id="sh1_'.$statusid.'" 
onload="checkRate(\''.$user.'\',\'status\',\'2\',\''.$id.'\')" > 0</span>`

However there are many status when the php loads, and when it finishes loading the page it doesn't trigger the onload functions. Is there a way to retrieve the id on each div that i download within the same loop?

Comment: post some code to support your question.

Comment: ok, I forgot to copy it, thas why it didnt appeared

Comment: the last para is still not understandable .. What is that you mean by multiple statuses ? id on each div that i download ?

Comment: I do a call on php and get the status on my profile. The problem is tha I am trying to trigger a function for each status after I get the posts, I guess I have to get the results on the fly instead of waiting to load the page.

Comment: Show `checkRate` function. Is there any errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a javascipt function every time you output the span. `onload` event is not supported by span tag, and won't be triggered. Use something like this:

```
<span id="sh1_'.$statusid.'" > 0</span>
?>
<script>
    checkRate('<?php print $user; ?>','status','2','<?php print $id; ?>');
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about it, yesterday I was burned out, also I don't need to call the javascript function since I can do all the gathering-info thing in the output.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see after some googling, there is no `onload` event on `span` elements.

Maybe you could use `onload` on the `body` element to trigger your code?

Comment: I got it, I was trying to do the calls in javascript when I should've got all the info in the php and echo it with the the posts and then update when people click on the like button. I am doing a like/nolike for comments and I was trying to get the results on loading the page, but instead I have to get them when I output the comments from php.